# LEFT JOIN not creating NULL records for unmatched rows

Tags: mysql, sql

`LEFT JOIN` supposedly joins 2 tables and creates `NULL` values when no matching record is found in the second (right) table. In the following timesheet scenario, I can't seem to get that to happen.

### users_table:

```
user_id
-------
frank
joe
jane
```

### timesheet_table:

```
user_id    month    hours
---------------------------
frank          jan     1
frank          jan     2
frank          jan     3
frank          feb     5
frank          mar     10
joe            jan     8
joe            feb     5
joe            feb     10
jane           jan     5
```

### mysql:

```
1 SELECT *
2 FROM users_table
3 LEFT JOIN(
4    SELECT
5        timesheet_table.user_id,
6        month,
7        SUM(hours)
8    FROM timesheet_table
9 ) timesheet_summary
10 ON users_table.user_id = timesheet_summary.user_id
11 GROUP BY month, users_table.user_id
```

Gives me something like this...

```
user_id    month    hours
---------------------------
frank        jan     6
joe          jan     8
jane         jan     5
frank        feb     5
joe          feb     15
frank        mar     10
```

But what I hoped for was...

```
user_id    month    hours
---------------------------
frank        jan     6
joe          jan     8
jane         jan     5
frank        feb     5
joe          feb     15
jane         feb     NULL
frank        mar     10
joe          mar     NULL
jane         mar     NULL
```

What is REALLY confusing me is that if I add a the following criteria between lines 8 and 9 it works (sort of)!

```
WHERE month = 'feb'
```

Gives me...

```
user_id    month    hours
---------------------------
frank        feb     5
joe          feb     15
jane         feb     NULL
```

Which is close but not exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You are missing a `group by` on user id and month, in your subquery (timesheet_summary derived table)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think the `GROUP` statement at line 11 is what's causing the error. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya true. I added that and still don't get NULL the rows I want when a user does not have a timesheet for a given month.

Comment: @alimbaronia I tried that and it just then gathers all timesheets for a given month into one total which is not good. They still need to be broken out by user.

Comment: @Vishnudev I want all months where there are any timesheets broken out by user. If the user doesn't have any timesheets, the row should be NULL for hours. This means that if 1 user had a timesheet for october say, all users should get rows for that month, the folks with no timesheet get a NULL.

Answer (score -1):

Actually that's what left join is supposed to do. You must use `inner join` instead.

[See this for an overall idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMmxB.png)

Comment: `Inner join` will return NULL rows if either of the tables queried return's null. This is not what the OP wants to do